# DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE (error generated in code for Python Crash Course)

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

All good with Django setup, virtual env, etc. until I simply run the 
models.py to define models.

Writing and running the code in VS Code for Windows. Run it in terminal 
session. I've tried editing the settings file in learning_log directory 
but did not solve the problem. For example, I added the last line to 
settings:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'learning_log',
]
```

Also tried adding this line to settings:

```
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=learning_log.settings
```

Here is the offending code:

```
from django.db import models

class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about."""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 
--snip--
```

Here is the error message from the terminal:

```
c:/Users/Jeff/py_projects/learning_log/models.py

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Users/Jeff/py_projects/learning_log/models.py", line 3, in 
<module>
class Topic(models.Model):
File "C:\Users\Jeff\py_projects\env\lib\site- 
packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 103, in __new__
app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
File "C:\Users\Jeff\py_projects\env\lib\site- 
packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 252, in get_containing_app_config
self.check_apps_ready()
File "C:\Users\Jeff\py_projects\env\lib\site- 
packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 134, in check_apps_ready
settings.INSTALLED_APPS
File "C:\Users\Jeff\py_projects\env\lib\site- 
packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
self._setup(name)
File "C:\Users\Jeff\py_projects\env\lib\site- 
packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 64, in _setup
% (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))

django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting 
INSTALLED_APPS, but settings are not configured. You must either define 
the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call 
settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Comment: What code/command are you executing when you get this error?

Comment: Here is the code, straight from the book/course:

from django.db import models

class Topic(models.Model):
    """A topic the user is learning about."""
    text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) 

    --snip--

Comment: Yeah but you don't get errors by just writing code into a file?  You have to be running some kind of command when you get this error.

Comment: I am using VS Code to write/edit code. Then right-click on the code to "Run Python File in Terminal." Then I see the output of my code in the terminal pane. Thanks Caleb.

Comment: Have you looked at your project in a browser? Have you visited http://localhost:8000 after issuing the runserver command?

Comment: Thanks japhyr. Yes the localhost and expected browser result for the project is fine I can confirm ...

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an `ImproperlyConfigured` error because you are trying to execute your `models.py` directly as a file.  This isn't what you want (I assume).  If you are trying to *migrate* your models (add them to the database), you will need to run `python3 manage.py makemigrations` and then `python3 manage.py migrate`.  If you are merely trying to start your server, you need to run `python3 manage.py runserver`.

If executing commands like this are unfamiliar to you, I'd recommend reading through the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/) found at the official docs.

Comment: Thanks. Ok but I have been successful writing and running code this way throughout the crash course. I did already run "migrate" successfully and also "runserver" successfully.

Comment: @Jeff When you try to run your models through VS, you are really running `python3 models.py`.

Comment: Also I assume you haven't been executing scripts with models or forms in them, or else you would get `ImproperlyConfigured` error.